# Running Testcontainers test in Windows against podman running in WSL

Tags: testcontainers, podman

I have Java app with Testcontainers. I've enabled podman service in WSL with the following command:

```
systemctl --user enable --now podman.socket
```

and also exported some env variables:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED="true"
```

The tests are working perfectly fine when started from WSL. However, I would like to be able to start them directly from Windows machine somehow setting the `DOCKER_HOST` to point to the podman running in WSL.

Is it possible? Can i somehow point Testcontainers to socket running in WSL?